# Dissapearing wifi connection

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, network-manager

I'm experiencing a problem with wifi connection on Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop (Lenovo Z50-70). My laptop can connect to wifi and it works fine, sometimes for a very long time but very often the connection breaks but only in practically because the wifi icon shows that everything should be fine. The ping says after ~15 secs "unknown host google.pl". I experienced this problem with many wifi networks and other (non-Linux) computers doesn't experience that. I have a second computer with Ubuntu and it works all fine but the computer has wired connection.

When I try to reconnect manually after that problem, system cannot connect again the network.

Only things that are fixing this problem are rebooting system and rebooting router & modem (not very sure of the second).

I discovered that using applications that use much internet (like downloading games from Steam, songs from Spotify, playing YouTube) makes the problem more probable to happen.

I'm not sure at all but I think it worked much better before I installed nVidia drivers. However I think this is just a coincidence because the internet sometimes work fine for very long (~1Gb of download) and sometimes not at all (~10Mb).

Everything works very fine when I use a wired connection directly from modem.

Maybe it's something with network card drivers?

EDIT: Network card info:
`lshw -c net
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 28:d2:44:9c:3d:6f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:61 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c3504000-c3504fff memory:c3500000-c3503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 90:48:9a:1a:d5:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.13.0-43-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c3400000-c3403fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.`

Comment: So what wifi card are you using?  Can you post the result of `lshw -c net` from terminal?

Comment: I edited the question posting what you requested.